# Best way to doing database task automatically in ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have OnlineCourse entity that have `StartDate` and `EndDate` property

i want to deny user if current datetime is between `StartDate` and `EndDate`
or disable this course based on today date time

i put below code in my Register ActionMethod

```
var startDate = currentOnlineCourse.StartDate
var endDate = currentOnlineCourse.EndDate

if (endDate >= DateTime.Now)
{
   currentOnlineCourse.Enable = false;
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
   ViewBag.Message = "You cannot apply this Course");
   return View();
}
```

my project contain many of this situation that need to preform some task(delete update ) database automatically
i want to create something like task scheduler and put this code in separate class and call it each date(ex 12:00 am of each day)
what is best way to do this??

Comment: You add a `ModelStateError` and return the view so the error message is displayed (and better, you can create a custom `ValidationAttribute` to give you bot client and server side validation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ViewBag.Message is dummy code that i put for test, but i search for way to disable registration automatically, i edit my question

Comment: Read my first comment!

Answer (score 1):

I like to handle custom validation logic by implementing `IValidatableObject` on the ViewModel:

```
public class OnlineCourseViewModel : IValidatableObject {
    public Datetime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Datetime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (EndDate > DateTime.Now) {
             yield return new ValidationResult(
                 "You cannot apply this Course",
                 new [] { "EndDate" }
             );
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller, check whether the model is valid:

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult Submit(OnlineCourseViewModel postData) {

     if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
         // Validation failed -> show errors
         return View("Submit", postData);
     }

     // Validation succeeded
     // do your stuff ...
}
```

In your View, render any validation errors:

```
@model OnlineCourseViewModel 

@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of `yield return` in this context?

Comment: @Extragorey you can remove it and return a `List<T>` or just check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

Comment: as i say in end of my question: i am searching for  task scheduler  for check do some change in my database